# Android Studio and Team Services Plugin: Change URL of Repository

Tags: android, azure-devops

I installed the Team Services Plugin for Android Studio. I imported code into a new respository on Team Services.

I would like to push the new stuff I have created (classes, xml files, etc) into the created repository, but, the URL of this repository has been changed. When I try push the new stuff, I get an error saying the repository can't be found.

Is there a way I can change the current remote repository to the new one, on Team Services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can run "git remote set-url" command from your local git repository to update the URL of remote repository. Refer to this link for details: [Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).